# Why ZIP Compression compresses a picture by only 4% less than the original picture?

Tags: windows-7

I am trying to use 7zip on a Windows 7, 64 bit. I followed the instructions (they are very simple) but the program compresses a few pictures by only 4% less than the original size. I cannot send them by email, not much change in size. What can be the cause?

Thank you Sergio

Comment: Could you please tell us the pictures' format?  Are they JPG, BMP, PNG, etc.?  It makes a big difference.  For example, a JPG picture already has a form of compression/loss built into the file type, so they typically won't shrink down too much inside a ZIP file.

Answer (score 6):

The answer is simple:

Most image formats are already compressed with a similar compression algorithm, mostly a variation of [Huffman coding](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Huffman_coding) for lossless aspects and [(Inverse)Discrete cosine transform](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Discrete_cosine_transform) for lossy aspects. So applying a (sometimes the same) compression method to already compressed data does not result in a significant decrease of file size.

An exception to this are the `RAW` formats (like `.RAW` or `.BMP`...). They are uncompressed and hence can be somewhat compressed with `ZIP` or other compression algorithms.

Comment: OK  I have to compress a number of pictures to a reasonable size to send them out by email

Comment: @SergioColacevich: Did you understand my answer? Unless your pictures are uncompressed like `.BMP` or `.RAW` images, they cannot be (significantly) compressed again. `.JPG`, `.PNG` and so on are already compressed. If this would be possible, every data could be reduced to a 1-byte file, which is obviously not the case.

Comment: I apologize, my previous comment was incorrectly stated. I meant I want to reduce the size, which could be obtained by reducing the resolution. I found a website that offered to do that for free and I did it but I only could reduce one picture at the time. If possible I would need to reduce several pictures at the time (they are in jpg), Sergio

Comment: Ah, ok then. This is (quite) a different question. I was assuming you wanted a lossless reduction of file size and in this case my answer is correct. But it seems you want a lossy reduction of file size by omitting information (like every second pixel). In this case you can use programs like [ImageMagick®](https://www.imagemagick.org) for batch converting many files. It's available for Windows, Linux and Mac.

Comment: Yes that would be the most desirable outcome but I understand from you that it is not achievable? Sergio